# If $f$ is differentible at a point $x \in [a,b]$, then $f$ is continuous at $x$.

Tags: real-analysis, derivatives

Proof. As $t\rightarrow x$, we have, by Theorem 4.4, (Baby Rudin, p.104)

$f\left( t\right) -f\left( x\right)$ = $\dfrac {f\left( t\right) -f\left( x\right) } {t-x}\cdot \left( t-x\right) \rightarrow f'(x).0=0.$

Note that I know it is equal to 0, yet why f is continous? My question is that I did not proof of theorem. Can you explain detailed this proof of theorem?

Comment: If $f(t)-f(x) \to 0$ as $t \to x$, then $\lim_{t \to x} f(t)=f(x)$, which is one way of phrasing what it means for $f$ to be continuous at $x$.

Comment: @SantiagoCanez I think the OP may be wondering how$$\lim_{t \to x}[f(t)-f(x)] = 0$$ implies existence of $$\lim_{t \to x}f(t)\text{.}$$
At least, that's how I interpret it.

Comment: Thaks for your comments.

Comment: @hayyam: In fact, I really like your proof (I would have never think about doing this way, but it's really intelligent). So BRAVO and thank you.

Answer (score 0):

By definition, we say $f$ is continuous at $x$ if 
$$\lim_{t\to x}f(t)=f(x)$$
which is **exactly** what the result tells.